# How to draw a dotted rectangle marquee on iphone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-graphics

How to draw rectangle something like this in iphone sdk using core graphics

[image: Screen Shot of the Crop Tool]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's five rectangles.

You construct a CGPath for the dotted line rectangle, stroke it, and then construct the four little CGPaths for the handles and stroke those.

Comment: Alternatively, build one CGPath for the handle, with a negative origin (e.g., -5, -5, 10, 10), then use the transformation matrix and the graphics state to stroke it in all four places.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically if you look at the actual iPhone reference documentation for `CGPath` You'll find a section about CGPathAddRect. After which you'll probably find the section of the 2D guide on [Painting a Path](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-CJBEIHHJ) useful.

### [CGPathAddRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000959-CH1g-CGPathAddRect)

Appends a rectangle to a mutable graphics path.

```
void CGPathAddRect (
   CGMutablePathRef path,
   const CGAffineTransform *m,
   CGRect rect
);
```

**Parameters**
*path*
The mutable path to change.

*m*
A pointer to an affine transformation matrix, or NULL if no transformation is needed. If specified, Quartz applies the transformation to the rectangle before adding it to the path.

*rect*
The rectangle to add.

**Discussion**
This is a convenience function that adds a rectangle to a path, using the following sequence of operations:

```
// start at origin
CGPathMoveToPoint (path, m, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));

// add bottom edge
CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, m, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));

// add right edge
CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, m, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect);

// add top edge
CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, m, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

// add left edge and close
CGPathCloseSubpath (path);
```

**Availability**
Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.

**Declared In**
CGPath.h

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend dispensing with the handles.  They make sense when you're using a mouse; with a touch screen, not so much.